# Listen for XSetSelectionOwner

Tags: xlib

Is possible to be notified that there is new selection owner? Does [XSetSelectionOwner](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XSetSelectionOwner.html) method cause any event broadcast? I wonder how x2x works. If there is no any way to be notified that there is new selection owner then x2x has to ask X servers in loop who is selection owner.

I suspect that:
x2x uses [XGetSelectionOwner](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetSelectionOwner.html) to ask both displays about current owner. If owner was changed on `Display 1` then x2x uses `XSetSelectionOwner` to become selection owner on `Display 2`. If user want paste data on Display 2, x2x on `display 2` works as intermediate and sends all received request to original client in `Display 1`. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you get selection ownership previous owner receive SelectionClear event:

> SelectionClear
>
> owner: WINDOW
>
> selection: ATOM
>
> time: TIMESTAMP
>
> This event is reported to the current owner of a selection and is
>   generated when a new owner is being defined by means of
>   SetSelectionOwner. The timestamp is the last-change time recorded for
>   the selection. The owner argument is the window that was specified by
>   the current owner in its SetSelectionOwner request.

Update: if you don't own selection, you can get notifications about selection change using [XFixes extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/fixesproto/fixesproto.txt):

```
6. Selection Tracking

Applications wishing to monitor the contents of current selections must
poll for selection changes.  XFIXES improves this by providing an event
delivered whenever the selection ownership changes.

6.2 Requests

SelectSelectionInput

        window:             Window
        selection:          Atom
        event-mask:         SETofSELECTIONEVENT

    Selects for events to be delivered to window when various causes of
    ownership of selection occur.  Subtype indicates the cause of the
    selection ownership change.  Owner is set to the current selection
    owner, or None.  Timestamp indicates the time the event was
    generated while selection-timestamp indicates the timestamp used to
    own the selection.
```

Comment: SelectionClear is reported only to the current owner of a selection. I want that my client be notified about new selection owner regardlessly that my client is current owner or not.